# Ошибка при попытке реализовать алгоритм Лемпеля-Зива

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня возникла проблема, не работает код приведенный ниже.

Даже не смею надеяться, что код хорошо работающий, мне хотя бы чтоб запустился.

Заранее спасибо!

---

Ошибка:

> ```
> "C:\python>python test.py
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "test.py", line 26, in <module>
>     strT1 = str(indexT) + listStr[i + 1]
> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
> ```

```
C:\python>"
```

---

формально, ругается на эту строку

```
 strT1 = str(indexT) + listStr[i + 1]
```

---

```
'''
Ziv Encoding
'''
str = "madma"
listStr = [] # для строки сообщения
listEn = []# для закодированного сообщения
for i in str:
    listStr.append(i)
#print(listStr)
i = 0
while(i < len(listStr)):
    if (i == 0):
        strT = ""# string to build a element of listEn
        strT = strT + "0" + listStr[i]
        listEn.append(strT)
        del strT

    j = 0
    while(j < len(listEn)):
        for k in range (0, len(listEn)):
            strT = ""
            strT = listEn[k]
            if (listStr[i] == strT[1:]):
                indexT = i + 1 # rememer the index of element to build the element of listEn
                strT1 = ""
                strT1 = str(indexT) + listStr[i + 1]
                listEn.append(strT1)
                del indexT
                del strT
                del strT1
                continue
            else:
                strT = ""# string to build a element of listEn
                strT = strT + "0" + listStr[i]
                listEn.append(strT)
                del strT

        j += 1
    i += 1
    print(listEn)
```

Answer (score 0):

Итак, игра продолжается)))

Ошибка была вызвана тем, что я по невнимательности объявил переменную str

```
str = "madma"
```

---

Но мои приключения не закончились.
Теперь цикл почему-то бесконечный.
Будем решать.